# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '' in 'field list' Using spring boot and JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've been banging my head against this all day and just can't seem to get it right... I'm sure some of you will have seen this and know the answer right away.

In my MYSQL database, I have table `RFQ_HEADER` that has primary key `rfq_no`. I have another table `line_item` that has composite primary key made up of `rfq_fk` and `item_no`

**Details**

**RfqHeader Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rfq_header")
public class RfqHeader implements Serializable  {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id @Column(name = "rfq_no")                    private String rfqNo;
@NotBlank @Column(name = "cust_no")             private String custNo; 
@NotBlank @Column(name = "terms_code")          private String termsCode; 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@NotBlank @Column(name = "rfq_datetime")        private Date receivedDate; 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "due_datetime")                  private Date dueDate; 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "acknow_datetime")               private Date acknowlegementDate; 
@Column(name = "mu_percent")                    private Double muPercent; 
@Column(name = "file_label")                    private String finalLabel;
@NotBlank @Column(name = "sent_by")             private String sentBy;
@NotBlank @Column(name = "fob")                 private String fob;
@NotBlank @Column(name = "ship_method")         private String shipMethod;
@Column(name = "notes")                         private String notes;
@Column(name = "internal_notes")                private String internalNotes;
@Column(name = "rfq_closed")                    private String rfqClosed;
@Column(name = "reason_closed")                 private String reasonClosed;
@Column(name = "qs_rfq_no")                     private String qsRfqNo;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=LineItem2.class, mappedBy="primaryKey.header2",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<LineItem2> lineItems2;

...getters/setters/constructors
```

**Embeddable Class - LineItem2PK**

```
@Embeddable
public class LineItem2Pk implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="rfq_pk",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String rfqPk;
@Column(name="item_no",insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String itemNo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="rfq_no", unique=true, updatable=false, insertable=false, nullable=false )
private RfqHeader header2;

...getters/setters/constructors
```

**LineItem2 Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="line_item")
public class LineItem2 implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId 
private LineItem2Pk primaryKey;

@Column(name="part_no")                         private String partNo;
@Column(name="quantity")                        private int quantity;
@Column(name="price_quoted")                    private double priceQuoted;
@Column(name="notes")                           private String notes;
@Column(name="internal_notes")                  private String internalNotes;
...getters/setters/constructors
```

**Console Log ERROR**

*

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column  'lineitem2x0_.header2_rfq_no' in 'field list'

*

```
Hibernate: select lineitem2x0_.header2_rfq_no as header8_0_, 
lineitem2x0_.item_no as item_no1_0_, lineitem2x0_.rfq_pk as rfq_pk2_0_, 
lineitem2x0_.internal_notes as internal3_0_, lineitem2x0_.notes as 
notes4_0_, lineitem2x0_.part_no as part_no5_0_, lineitem2x0_.price_quoted as 
price_qu6_0_, lineitem2x0_.quantity as quantity7_0_ from line_item 
lineitem2x0_ where lineitem2x0_.rfq_pk=?
2018-06-06 21:44:03.789  WARN 12424 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2018-06-06 21:44:03.789 ERROR 12424 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 
'lineitem2x0_.header2_rfq_no' in 'field list'
2018-06-06 21:44:03.793 ERROR 12424 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]. 
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] 
in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested 
exception is 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not 
extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] 
with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 
'lineitem2x0_.header2_rfq_no' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~ 
[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: Add the missing column to the table? Or remove the reference that is stored in the column?

Comment: missing column? `header2_rfq_no` is referencing `private RfqHeader header2` column `rfq_no` in `LIne_item` table. Remove the reference that is stored in the column? Are you referring to Foreign key reference?

Comment: The exception seems to complain that `lineitem2x0_.header2_rfq_no` does not exist, which gets introduced through `LineItem2PK.header2`. So removing that reference or adding that column should fix it.